# Different IP addresses in production and test environment how to handle it automaticaly

Tags: reactjs, django, git

I have an app with django backend and react frontend. When testing and coding i run my django app on local server 127.0.0.1:8000 and connecting all my react requests to those endpoints. However in production my django app run on a different ip address and everytime i changed my code and push my reactjs app to production server i have to change all the endpoints ip's.

What is the best way to handle it? (as a source control i use **git** i do not know if it makes any differences)

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/ you should  have to have different .env files

Comment: Use env files. Typically .env.developement and .env. Look @Kalhan.Toress link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the `axios.defaults.baseURL` depending on the `window.location.origin`. Here is my setting:

```
if (window.location.origin === "http://localhost:3000") {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
} else {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = window.location.origin;
}
```

The above config is from my article  [Docker-Compose for Django and React with Nginx reverse-proxy and Let's Encrypt certificate](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/docker-compose-django-react-nginx-let-s-encrypt/). I'm serving React with nginx, and have reverse-proxy to Django (also in nginx), that's why for production setting I'm just using the same address. In the case of development, I have REST API at `127.0.0.1:8000`.

I prefer this dynamic setting than settin `env` files because I don't need to set any environment variables.